# How can I get browserSync running with gulp?

Tags: gulp, browser-sync

I'm following the docs here:
http://www.browsersync.io/docs/gulp/

This is what I've built so far:

```
var gulp = require('gulp') ;
var sass = require('gulp-sass') ;
var watch  = require('gulp-watch') ;
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create() ;



gulp.task('serve',  ['sass'],  function() {

    gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
        browserSync.init({
            //proxy: "mydevserver",
        server : ".",
            files: ['./index.html', './css/**']
        });
    });

    gulp.watch("./css/**").on('change', browserSync.reload);

} ) ;

// Compile sass into CSS & auto-inject into browsers
gulp.task('sass', function() {
    return gulp.src("./sass/**")
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("./css/"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

gulp.task('default', ['serve']) ;
```

When I run 'grunt' from the terminal, the 'sass' task works. But I have no indication that browserSync runs. The terminal gives me no feedback on anything relevant to browserSync. If I navigate to 'localhost:3000' or 'localhost:3001' there is nothing running.

Answer (score 0):

You create a task in a task, that's why you didn't see anything about browserSync, and you don't need to call `BrowserSync.create()` and no need to use `gulp.watch`, browserSync will automatically watch the files you have specified in its config.

Correction :

```
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
gulp.task('serve',  ['sass'],  function() {
    browserSync({
        //proxy: "mydevserver",
    server : ".",
       files: ['./index.html', './css/**']
    });
} ) ;
```

Comment: looks like the only difference there is the removal of the watch task? If I do that, 'gulp serve' just compiles sass once and doesn't watch anything. And browserSync still doesn't run.

Comment: I have edited the code, just use browserSync as a function, no need to use `browserSync.init()` or `.create()`